# Как слить список в строку в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = int(input())
b = [1] * a
for i in range (1, a+1):
    b[i-1] = [[i] * i]
print(b)
```

При вводе a = 5, получается такой список:

```
[[[1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3]], [[4, 4, 4, 4]], [[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]]
```

Как его преобразовать в строку вида: `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(', '.join(str(x) for [c] in b for x in c))
```

Только проще сразу сформировать нужную строку без промежуточных списков

```py
n = int(input())
print(', '.join(str(x) for x in range(n + 1) for _ in range(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

true pythonic way:

```
b = [[[1]], [[2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3]], [[4, 4, 4, 4]], [[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]]
print(', '.join(list(map(lambda x: ', '.join(list(map(lambda y: ', '.join(list(map(str, y))), x))), b))))

# 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
```